# labstreaminglayer missing liblsl32.so

Tags: linux, libraries

After installing matlab, I tried to run the ReceiveData function, and it gives me the following message:

> Apparently the file "path/liblsl-Matlab/bin/liblsl32.so" is missing on your computer. Cannot load the lab streaming layer.

You can download any matlab lsl version and you will not find liblsl32.so.  Does anyone know why the 32 bit support file is missing (did they stop supporting Linux 32 bit)?

Comment: Two second Google search to the project home page: "The library is general-purpose and cross-platform (Win/Linux/MacOS, 32/64)"

Comment: @fixer1234 I have download many versions, all of them does not contain `liblsl32.so` !

Comment: Are you sure that file is required?  Have you tried it after installation, it didn't work, and you traced the error to this missing file?

Comment: @fixer1234, Yes I'm sure, you can download any matlab lsl version and you will not find it (I hope that I'm wrong, and it's exist).
for your question about tracing the error, I tried to run `ReceiveData` function, matlab gives me the following message: 
`Apparently the file "path/liblsl-Matlab/bin/liblsl32.so" is missing on your
computer. Cannot load the lab streaming layer.`